# Why is “I ate a sandwich to the school” wrong?

Tags: prepositions

“In the school, I ate a sandwich” means “I ate a sandwich, being in the school.”

Likewise, can “to the school, I ate a sandwich” mean “I ate a sandwich, walking to the school”?

to: used as a function word to indicate movement or an action or condition suggestive of movement toward a place, person, or thing reached

Comment: You cannot eat in a certain direction, but you can walk in one. “I ate my sandwich walking to the school” is correct.

Comment: How would anyone know what you were doing? There is no verb! You could be running, hopping, skipping, and so on.

Comment: @fev I mean motion.

Comment: @FeliniusRex There’s verb “ate.”

Comment: @user3330 The verb "to eat", in any language, can happen while moving from one place to another, but that must be stated by a different verb. "Eat" does not contain this connotation. Unless you [eat pavement](http://onlineslangdictionary.com/meaning-definition-of/eat-pavement#:~:text=verb,contact%20with%20a%20stationary%20object.).

Comment: @fev Even though a prepositional phrase is at the front?

Comment: @user3330 huh? You kinda lost me there...

Comment: You could say "**On the way to the school**, I ate a sandwich."

Comment: @stangdon I mean it! Why not “to”!!

Comment: @user3330 I think the only answer is "because that's not the way that *to* works."  You don't "eat to something" in English.

Comment: @user3330 Sorry, but you need a verb to describe what you are doing. "to the school" doesn't tell what you are doing. You could be hopping to the school, running to the school, or skipping to the school. The preposition "to" does not mean "walking to".

Comment: When some friends were drinking champagne one said "Let's drink to the school!"

Comment: @WeatherVane That's a pretty good counter-example.  I also thought of another: "You should eat to regain your strength."  So I'll reframe my words a bit: we don't "eat *to* something" in the sense of "motion towards" in English.

Comment: In the context of describing which direction a verb is taking place, *to* is part of a prepositional verb and is always paired with its verb. In your example, you have omitted the verb that goes with *to*. It certainly isn't *ate*, because you don't eat in a direction. "In the school" is not part of a prepositional verb. It modifies the noun.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I have to disagree with you about "in the school" modifying the noun.  What if there were no noun, as in "I slept in the school"?

Comment: @stangdon In your example, “I” is the noun being described by the preposition.

Comment: "*I ate a sandwich (when I was)*  **at** *school*" and "*I ate a sandwhich (while I was)* **going to** *school*" would be the more common way of saying it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a more interesting question than I thought at first.

When we select a preposition, we do so to show a relationship between things, people, events, and so on. Most prepositions describe a relationship between a thing and a location: **on, in, at, above, below**, and so on. Almost any kind of action or state can exist with reference to a location, and **eat** is one of these. If you use such a preposition to describe another kind of relationship, your listener's brain might resist the idea. It is hard to know exactly what is meant by the following:

> I ate a sandwich in a question.

But the brain will try to make sense of it. Maybe it means "during" a question. Maybe there is a new chain of restaurants called Question. So there is a small degree of flexibility with **in.**

In contrast, some relationships are so specialized that the brain will reject a sentence that does not meet certain requirements. Try this:

> I ate a sandwich between the school.

The word "between" requires at least two locations (and usually only two). The brain cannot make sense of such a statement if only one location has been named. We respond by saying, "The situation requires a different preposition" or perhaps "**between** requires a different situation."

Something like the following is required for **between**:

> I ate a sandwich between the school and the supermarket.

I've devoted a lot of space to showing you that prepositions can have flexible requirements or absolute requirements.

Which leads us to this:

**To** indicates a direction, not a location, and can only be used when motion is indicated. This is an absolute requirement. You can **walk, run, drive,** or **fly to the school.** You can **throw a ball to the school.** For that matter, you can **throw a sandwich to the school.** All of these actions describe some sort of direction.

But you cannot **eat a sandwich to the school,** because **eat** does not indicate any kind of direction, and we do not experience **eat** as a kind of motion.

Answer (score 0):

The OP's sentence is "*To the school, I ate a sandwich.*"

I believe that it's the word order which is to blame. There's nothing "wrong" in saying:

1. *I drank a coffee (while going) to work*
2. *I ate a sandwich (on my way) to school*

Note that the definite article is removed from "the school".  It's conversational English using ellipsis, the speaker is leaving out information e.g *while going*,  which is not essential to meaning.